# Cannot delete/erase APFS volume

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, mojave, ssd, apfs

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) running Mac OS Mojave. When I boot it up, it shows a grey screen with a question mark on a folder.

I have figured out that the issue is with the internal SSD as I can boot from a USB installer with Mojave just fine. I can see the internal disk with `diskutil` and also see `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/` from the terminal. I was able to recover the few files this way that I hadn't backed up earlier. However this was too slow as even an `ls` command on the Macintosh HD Volume takes a couple of minutes to execute and the `system.log` in `/var/log` shows loads of error messages of this type: `Kernel[0]: disk1: I/O error.` But, I managed to get the files I needed.

Now I want to wipe the SSD or atleast erase the data from the `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/`, but I am not able to do that. I tried Disk Utility but it just hangs every time I open it and running `diskutil` from the terminal on always ends up with some error. I have tried `verifyVolume`, `repairVolume`, `eraseVolume`, `deleteVolume`, `deleteContainer` and `eraseDisk` with `diskutil` but they all end with an error which looks something like this: `Error: -69877: Couldn't open device` or similar to this.

I found this answer [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251710920) to delete the APFS partition using a bootable USB with Linux Mint. This ended with an error message too saying `Input/output error`.

Is there any way I can wipe the SSD clean?

The disk and the volume are not encrypted and I have also tried resetting NVRAM, PRAM and SMC but none of that helped. Booting up into Recovery Mode doesn't help either. It shows a spinning globe but there is no progress bar, and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
diskutil zerodisk force diskX
```

Where **diskX** is to be replaced by the internal SSD indentifier.

But given the previous errors, I doubt the effectiveness.
The best solution is to remove this SSD by following this link: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2015+SSD+Replacement/48251

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I passed the `force` option when I tried earlier. I suspect that `eraseVolume` and `eraseDisk` would be using `zerodisk` in the background to erase the disk but I will give it a go anyway.

Comment: No eraseVolume or erasedisk remain at the logical structures level while zerodisk attempts to erase all information from the disk, including structures. But I have a doubt seen the I / O errors. It will certainly be necessary to change the SSD. You have the option of replacing the original Apple SSDs with NVME M2 models with adapter, much cheaper and just as efficient.

Comment: No luck here, but received a different error this time: 
`Error -69759: Securely erasing data to prevent recovery failed. Underlying error: 5`

I think I have seen error message `5` before when I tried to format the disk from Linux Mint.

Comment: Have try open the Mac, extract the SSD, clean contacts and remount it? This link can help you : https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2015+SSD+Replacement/48251

Comment: I don't have any tools on me at the moment to do this, but it looks like that is the only alternative. Thanks.